# How to solve System.Drawing - Parameter is not valid

Tags: c#, .net, image, winforms, desktop

How to solve System.Drawing Parameter is not valid
    when I use  code:

```
string img2 = "http://13.228.146.249:8080/jcr/groups/629.png;
byte[] toBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(img2);
if (toBytes != null)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(toBytes);
    ms.Position = 0;
    picboxserver.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

picboxserver is picturebox type.

Comment: You’re trying to put the URL string as the image, not the data that resides at that URL.

Comment: picboxserver.ImageLocation = img2;

Answer (score 0):

You want to at `http://13.228.146.249:8080/jcr/groups/629.png` inside your PictureBox? in that case, simply use the [`Load()`-Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6ak7was(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
picboxserver.Load("http://13.228.146.249:8080/jcr/groups/629.png");
```